# doesn't support architecture 'arm64, doesn't support architecture 'armhf'

Tags: apt, package-management, updates

When I try to update, I am having this issue:

```
$ sudo apt-get update
Hit:2 http://ports.ubuntu.com xenial InRelease
Hit:3 http://ports.ubuntu.com xenial-security InRelease                                                         
Ign:1 http://packages.erlang-solutions.com/debian xenial InRelease      
Hit:4 http://ports.ubuntu.com xenial-updates InRelease
Hit:6 http://ports.ubuntu.com xenial-backports InRelease                
Hit:5 http://packages.erlang-solutions.com/debian xenial Release
Reading package lists... Done                     
N: Skipping acquire of configured file 'contrib/binary-arm64/Packages' as repository 'http://binaries.erlang-solutions.com/debian xenial InRelease' doesn't support architecture 'arm64'
N: Skipping acquire of configured file 'contrib/binary-armhf/Packages' as repository 'http://binaries.erlang-solutions.com/debian xenial InRelease' doesn't support architecture 'armhf'
```

The output of `lscpu`:

```
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ lscpu
Architecture:          aarch64
Byte Order:            Little Endian
CPU(s):                4
On-line CPU(s) list:   0-3
Thread(s) per core:    1
Core(s) per socket:    1
Socket(s):             4
CPU max MHz:           1512.0000
CPU min MHz:           100.0000
Hypervisor vendor:     (null)
Virtualization type:   full
```

Comment: I have added `lscpu` output. @Melebius

Answer (score 3):

The packager does not publish packages for arm64 or armhf in that repository, only [i386 and amd64](http://packages.erlang-solutions.com/debian/dists/xenial/Release).

If you want this software for Arm, you can either ask the vendor to compile it for arm, or if it's open source, recompile it yourself.

Comment: I am not clear your second comments, can you explore me please @vidarlo

Comment: If it's open source software you can compile it for ARM yourself. If you don't have the source code, you have to ask the vendor to do this.